# Applying functions in dplyr pipes

Tags: r, dplyr, pipeline

Given a data frame like `data`:

```r
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c('a','b'), each= 100),
                   value = rnorm(200))
```

We want to filter values for `group == b` using `dplyr` and use `boxplot.stats` to identify outliers:

```r
library(dplyr)
data%>%
  filter(group == 'b')%>%
  summarise(out.stats = boxplot.stats(value))
```

This returns the error `Column` out.stats `must be length 1 (a summary value), not 4`, why does this not work? How do you apply functions like this inside a pipe?

Comment: `data %>% filter(group == 'b') %>% pull(value) %>% boxplot.stats()` doesn't seem to be what you are looking for. But note that the output of `boxplot.stats` is a *list*  with 4 elements.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks this makes sense, if you wanted to manipulate this further by extracting just the `$out` from the `boxplot.stats()` function, how do you do that? for instance, you cant do `data %>% filter(group == 'b') %>% pull(value) %>% boxplot.stats()$out`?

Comment: Update to `dplyr >= 1.0.0`: From NEWS: "`summarise()` can create summaries of greater than length 1"

Comment: Continue the pipe with `%>% '[['('stats')`. And @Henrik's comment works.

Comment: @RuiBarradas ahh I see, apologies, one more similar question if you don't mind, this is very helpful for me: what if we want to return the row numbers that go with `boxplot.stats()$out` from the pipe? so if we did `b<-data%>%filter(group=='b')` outside of the pipe), we could have used: `which(b$value %in% boxplot.stats(b$value)$out)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answers to the question and to the last comment to the question, where the OP asks for the row numbers of the outliers.

> what if we want to return the row numbers that go with
> `boxplot.stats()$out` from the pipe? so if we did
> `b<-data%>%filter(group=='b')` outside of the pipe, we could have used:
> `which(b$value %in% boxplot.stats(b$value)$out)`

This is done by `left_join`ing with the original data.

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c('a','b'), each= 100),
                   value = rnorm(200))

data %>% filter(group == 'b') %>% pull(value) %>% 
  boxplot.stats() %>% '[['('out') %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  left_join(data, by = c('.' = 'value'))
#          . group
#1  3.043766     b
#2 -2.732220     b
#3 -2.855759     b
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the new version of `dplyr` which can also return `summarise` with more than one row

```
library(dplyr) # >= 1.0.0
data%>%
  filter(group == 'b')%>%
  summarise(out.stats = boxplot.stats(value))
#                                              out.stats
#1 -2.4804222, -0.7546693, 0.1304050, 0.6390749, 2.2682247
#2                                                     100
#3                                 -0.08980661, 0.35061653
#4                                               -3.014914
```